# Magento 2 Product rating is not visible in all store views?

Tags: magento2, frontend, store-view, phtml, ratings

**I have two store views in my website some products having rating stars and displaying them is fine in default store view.**

While switching into another store view the rating stars are disappearing from that place.

The entire catalog is same for all the stores in my website. How can i Make them visible in all store views.

Comment: have you approved user rating from admin panel?

Comment: yes Approved @Rakesh.Can we give admin settings like in any store view if user rate some product it should display on all store views. ?

Comment: currently I selected both store views manually by going to admin user ratings.So coming fine.but I need this as above mentioned.

Comment: But when you done approved in admin at that time you have to select store view for display rating in both store.

Comment: This post may be help you http://www.emagentosupport.com/2018/12/magento-2-rating-not-visible-in-store.html

Answer (score 11):

You have to enable rating from admin for each store view :

**Stores > Rating** :

[image]

Now Select Price, Quality, Rating and Value, Open Page from click on above,

**Set Your Store from Visibility.**

```
Set Is Active to checked.
```

Comment: normal rating form and rating stars are already enabled.After user gave rating to that product, those rating stars i.e product average rating is not visible for all the store views.

Comment: exactly, you need to go on each product's review to enable it on all store views...

Comment: Stores > Attributes > Rating